# Is there a way to get rid of unnecessary time delay in Calamari-ocr text detection engine?

Tags: python, machine-learning, computer-vision, ocr, lstm

I have been playing with the Calamari-ocr text detection engine. [Calamari ocr repo](https://github.com/Calamari-OCR/calamari)
Something I have noticed is that when one runs a prediction, it spews a lot of messages, and by the time it actually makes a prediction and tells you that it took say 1 second to make the prediction, it has already taken 5 seconds for me to actually get to that prediction. i.e. if I time the "prediction command", it takes 5 seconds roughly, even though, the model tells me it took only 1 seconds for the model to make a prediction.

My investigation led me to [this](https://github.com/Calamari-OCR/calamari/blob/master/calamari_ocr/scripts/predict.py) script in repo where the prediction is happening. And then even further I pin-pointed the `MultiPredictor` class to be responsible for this (line 92). So I looked at where that class is defined and I found that it is defined [here](https://github.com/Calamari-OCR/calamari/blob/master/calamari_ocr/ocr/predictor.py).
But I cannot find what in there is causing the spew of messages and warnings that cause the delay for me.

Here is the code snippet I used to make a prediction and time it:

```
import subprocess
import time

cmd = ['calamari-predict', '--checkpoint', '/opt/working/base_model/model_Calamari_1.ckpt.json', '--files', '/opt/working/data/*.png']
start_time = time.time()
subprocess.run(cmd)
print(time.time()-start_time)
```

Note that I have already have the calamari package installed  as well the required dependencies as per the repo's instructions.

Here is the provided response when I run the prediction:

```
Found 1 files in the dataset
Checkpoint version 2 is up-to-date.
2020-09-02 14:50:49.243030: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:59] Could not load dynamic library 'libcudart.so.10.1'; dlerror: libcudart.so.10.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2020-09-02 14:50:49.243090: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:29] Ignore above cudart dlerror if you do not have a GPU set up on your machine.
2020-09-02 14:50:50.390703: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:59] Could not load dynamic library 'libcuda.so.1'; dlerror: libcuda.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2020-09-02 14:50:50.390770: W tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:312] failed call to cuInit: UNKNOWN ERROR (303)
2020-09-02 14:50:50.390814: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:156] kernel driver does not appear to be running on this host (6d0f92664ca6): /proc/driver/nvidia/version does not exist
2020-09-02 14:50:50.391069: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN)to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX2 FMA
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2020-09-02 14:50:50.396503: I tensorflow/core/platform/profile_utils/cpu_utils.cc:104] CPU Frequency: 1896005000 Hz
2020-09-02 14:50:50.396883: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service 0x55ca0736dbb0 initialized for platform Host (this does not guarantee that XLA will be used). Devices:
2020-09-02 14:50:50.396937: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:176]   StreamExecutor device (0): Host, Default Version
Model: "functional_1"
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
input_data (InputLayer)         [(None, None, 48, 1) 0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_0 (Conv2D)               (None, None, 48, 40) 400         input_data[0][0]                 
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
pool2d_1 (MaxPooling2D)         (None, None, 24, 40) 0           conv2d_0[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_1 (Conv2D)               (None, None, 24, 60) 21660       pool2d_1[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
pool2d_3 (MaxPooling2D)         (None, None, 12, 60) 0           conv2d_1[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
reshape (Reshape)               (None, None, 720)    0           pool2d_3[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
bidirectional (Bidirectional)   (None, None, 400)    1473600     reshape[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
input_sequence_length (InputLay [(None, 1)]          0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dropout (Dropout)               (None, None, 400)    0           bidirectional[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
tf_op_layer_FloorDiv (TensorFlo [(None, 1)]          0           input_sequence_length[0][0]      
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
logits (Dense)                  (None, None, 29)     11629       dropout[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
tf_op_layer_FloorDiv_1 (TensorF [(None, 1)]          0           tf_op_layer_FloorDiv[0][0]       
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
softmax (Softmax)               (None, None, 29)     0           logits[0][0]                     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
input_data_params (InputLayer)  [(None, 1)]          0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
tf_op_layer_Cast (TensorFlowOpL [(None, 1)]          0           tf_op_layer_FloorDiv_1[0][0]     
==================================================================================================
Total params: 1,507,289
Trainable params: 1,507,289
Non-trainable params: 0
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
None
Prediction:   0%|                                                                                       | 0/1 [00:00<?, ?it/s]
barcode_0: '‪CLK0SU0M((141707‬'
Prediction: 100%|███████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 1/1 [00:01<00:00,  1.52s/it]
Prediction of 1 models took 1.5640497207641602s
Average sentence confidence: 85.41%
All files written
4.881764888763428
```

As you can see the model indicated that it only took 1.5640497207641602 seconds to make a prediction, but at the bottom you can see that it actually took 4.881764888763428 seconds.

To make sure that running the predict function as a subroutine is not the culprit for the time delay, I refactored the code for making predictions and ran it :

```
from bidi.algorithm import get_base_level

from google.protobuf.json_format import MessageToJson

from calamari_ocr import __version__
from calamari_ocr.utils.glob import glob_all
from calamari_ocr.ocr.datasets import DataSetType, create_dataset, DataSetMode
from calamari_ocr.ocr import MultiPredictor
from calamari_ocr.ocr.voting import voter_from_proto
from calamari_ocr.proto import VoterParams, Predictions, CTCDecoderParams

import os
import cv2
import time
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger()


class PredictionAttrs:
    def __init__(self):
        """Atributes:
            List all image files that shall be processed
            --files

            Optional list of additional text files. E.g. when updating Abbyy prediction, this parameter must be used for the xml files.
            --text_files

            Used to identify the DatasetType
            --dataset

            Define the prediction extension. This parameter can be used to override ground truth files.
            --extension

            Path to the checkpoint without file extension
            --checkpoint

            Number of processes to use"
            -j --processes

            The batch size during the prediction (number of lines to process in parallel)
            --batch_size

            Print additional information
            --verbose

            The voting algorithm to use. Possible values: confidence_voter_default_ctc (default), confidence_voter_fuzzy_ctc, sequence_voter
            --voter

            By default the prediction files will be written to the same directory as the given files. You can use this argument to specify a specific output dir for the prediction files.
            --output_dir

            Write: Predicted string, labels; position, probabilities and alternatives of chars to a .pred (protobuf) file
            --extended_prediction_data

            Extension format: Either pred or json. Note that json will not print logits.
            --extended_prediction_data_format

            Do not show any progress bars
            --no_progress_bars

            List of text files that will be used to create a dictionary
            --dictionary

            Number of beams when using the CTCWordBeamSearch decoder
            --beam_width

            # dataset extra args
            --dataset_pad
            --pagexml_text_index
        """
        self.files = []
        self.checkpoint = []
        self.processes = 1
        self.batch_size = 1
        self.verbose = True
        self.voter = "confidence_voter_default_ctc"
        self.output_dir = None
        self.extended_prediction_data = False
        self.extended_prediction_data_format = "json"
        self.no_progress_bars = True
        self.extension = None
        self.dataset = DataSetType.FILE
        self.text_files = None
        self.pagexml_text_index = 0
        self.beam_width = 25
        self.dictionary = []
        self.dataset_pad = None


class CalamariPredict(object):
    def __init__(self, checkpoint_path, file):
        """This class utilises the attributes of PredictionAttrs class and
         uses the specified checkpoint to predict the text for the input file.
         For predicting the method run() is called.

        Arguments:
            checkpoint_path: Path to checkpoint files
        """
        self.args = PredictionAttrs()
        self.args.checkpoint = checkpoint_path
        self.args.files = file

        # add json as extension, resolve wildcard, expand user, ... and remove .json again
        self.args.checkpoint = [(cp if cp.endswith(".json") else cp + ".json") for cp in self.args.checkpoint]
        self.args.checkpoint = glob_all(self.args.checkpoint)
        self.args.checkpoint = [cp[:-5] for cp in self.args.checkpoint]

        self.args.extension = (
            self.args.extension if self.args.extension else DataSetType.pred_extension(self.args.dataset)
        )

        # create ctc decoder
        ctc_decoder_params = self.create_ctc_decoder_params(self.args)

        # create voter
        voter_params = VoterParams()
        voter_params.type = VoterParams.Type.Value(self.args.voter.upper())
        self.voter = voter_from_proto(voter_params)

        # predict for all models
        self.predictor = MultiPredictor(
            checkpoints=self.args.checkpoint,
            batch_size=self.args.batch_size,
            processes=self.args.processes,
            ctc_decoder_params=ctc_decoder_params,
        )
        # checks
        if self.args.extended_prediction_data_format not in ["pred", "json"]:
            raise Exception("Only 'pred' and 'json' are allowed extended prediction data formats")
        # load files
        if self.args.dataset == DataSetType.FILE:
            input_image_files = glob_all(self.args.files)
            if self.args.text_files:
                self.args.text_files = glob_all(self.args.text_files)

        elif self.args.dataset == DataSetType.RAW:
            input_image_files = file

        # skip invalid files and remove them, there wont be predictions of invalid files
        self.dataset = create_dataset(
            self.args.dataset,
            DataSetMode.PREDICT,
            input_image_files,
            self.args.text_files,
            skip_invalid=True,
            remove_invalid=True,
            args={"text_index": self.args.pagexml_text_index, "pad": self.args.dataset_pad,},
        )

        if len(self.dataset) == 0:
            raise Exception(
                "Empty dataset provided. Check your files argument (got {})!".format(self.args.files)
            )

        do_prediction = self.predictor.predict_dataset(
            self.dataset, progress_bar=not self.args.no_progress_bars
        )

        avg_sentence_confidence = 0
        n_predictions = 0

        self.dataset.prepare_store()

        # output the voted results to the appropriate files
        for result, sample in do_prediction:
            n_predictions += 1
            for i, p in enumerate(result):
                p.prediction.id = "fold_{}".format(i)

            # vote the results (if only one model is given, this will just return the sentences)
            prediction = self.voter.vote_prediction_result(result)
            prediction.id = "voted"
            sentence = prediction.sentence
            avg_sentence_confidence += prediction.avg_char_probability

        print(sentence)
    def create_ctc_decoder_params(self, args):
        """Method for returning the ctc decoder params

        Arguments:
            args: args from an instance of class PredictionAttrs

        Returns:
            params -- ctc decoder params.
        """
        params = CTCDecoderParams()
        params.beam_width = args.beam_width
        params.word_separator = " "

        if args.dictionary and len(args.dictionary) > 0:
            dictionary = set()
            logger.info(f"Creating dictionary")
            for path in glob_all(args.dictionary):
                with open(path, "r") as f:
                    dictionary = dictionary.union({word for word in f.read().split()})

            params.dictionary[:] = dictionary
            logger.info("Dictionary with {} unique words successfully created.".format(len(dictionary)))
        else:
            args.dictionary = None

        if args.dictionary:
            logger.info(
                f"USING A LANGUAGE MODEL IS CURRENTLY EXPERIMENTAL ONLY. NOTE: THE PREDICTION IS VERY SLOW!"
            )
            params.type = CTCDecoderParams.CTC_WORD_BEAM_SEARCH

        return params


if __name__ == "__main__":
    start_time = time.time()
    pred = CalamariPredict(['/opt/working/base_model/model_Calamari_1.ckpt.json'],'/opt/working/data/*.png')
    print(time.time()-start_time)
```

But still this is what I got:

```
Checkpoint version 2 is up-to-date.
2020-09-02 15:23:00.328806: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:59] Could not load dynamic library 'libcudart.so.10.1'; dlerror: libcudart.so.10.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2020-09-02 15:23:00.328876: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:29] Ignore above cudart dlerror if you do not have a GPU set up on your machine.
2020-09-02 15:23:01.536020: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:59] Could not load dynamic library 'libcuda.so.1'; dlerror: libcuda.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2020-09-02 15:23:01.536096: W tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:312] failed call to cuInit: UNKNOWN ERROR (303)
2020-09-02 15:23:01.536122: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:156] kernel driver does not appear to be running on this host (6d0f92664ca6): /proc/driver/nvidia/version does not exist
2020-09-02 15:23:01.536450: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN)to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX2 FMA
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2020-09-02 15:23:01.542147: I tensorflow/core/platform/profile_utils/cpu_utils.cc:104] CPU Frequency: 1896005000 Hz
2020-09-02 15:23:01.542953: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service 0x560df22dbb30 initialized for platform Host (this does not guarantee that XLA will be used). Devices:
2020-09-02 15:23:01.543009: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:176]   StreamExecutor device (0): Host, Default Version
Model: "functional_1"
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
input_data (InputLayer)         [(None, None, 48, 1) 0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_0 (Conv2D)               (None, None, 48, 40) 400         input_data[0][0]                 
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
pool2d_1 (MaxPooling2D)         (None, None, 24, 40) 0           conv2d_0[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_1 (Conv2D)               (None, None, 24, 60) 21660       pool2d_1[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
pool2d_3 (MaxPooling2D)         (None, None, 12, 60) 0           conv2d_1[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
reshape (Reshape)               (None, None, 720)    0           pool2d_3[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
bidirectional (Bidirectional)   (None, None, 400)    1473600     reshape[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
input_sequence_length (InputLay [(None, 1)]          0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dropout (Dropout)               (None, None, 400)    0           bidirectional[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
tf_op_layer_FloorDiv (TensorFlo [(None, 1)]          0           input_sequence_length[0][0]      
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
logits (Dense)                  (None, None, 29)     11629       dropout[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
tf_op_layer_FloorDiv_1 (TensorF [(None, 1)]          0           tf_op_layer_FloorDiv[0][0]       
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
softmax (Softmax)               (None, None, 29)     0           logits[0][0]                     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
input_data_params (InputLayer)  [(None, 1)]          0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
tf_op_layer_Cast (TensorFlowOpL [(None, 1)]          0           tf_op_layer_FloorDiv_1[0][0]     
==================================================================================================
Total params: 1,507,289
Trainable params: 1,507,289
Non-trainable params: 0
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
None
Prediction of 1 models took 1.556354284286499s
CLK0SU0M((141707
3.4778225421905518
```

As you can see the timed prediction time is still twice as much as the claimed prediction time.

Comment: Running a subprocess means that everything has to be loaded from scratch (libraries, python runtime, tensorflow, etc), there is all your extra time to make a prediction. Maybe just use it as a python library and not through a command line interface

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy No. I tried running the functions inside the prediction script as well and still got the same outcome. All those warnings seem to be triggered by the MultiPredictor class. When I take it out, the warnings and the prediction go away lol

Comment: I don't see any of those details in your question, so I cannot really comment.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy did you look at the links I have provided?

Comment: Yes, and I do not see what you mean, these warnings come from when TensorFlow is imported, which happens again because you are running a subprocess.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy. I refactored the code and ran it (please see my edits in the question). But the same discrepancy still exists

Comment: I think what you need to consider is that there is no "discrepancy", you are measuring two different things, one is just the model prediction time, and another is the whole code that leads to  making a prediction, including loading frameworks, loading data, model, etc. These times will never match because all of these steps are actually necessary to make a prediction. You can only reduce them to a minimum.